# Posterior distribution with multiple parameters

Tags: bayesian

The data are observations of, $x$, the length of time in excess of $14$ days that it took for a random sample of $10$ grasshoppers infected with a fungal disease to die, where the times are measured from infection.

It is believed that a gamma distribution may be a good model here, so that the p.d.f. of $x$ is

$$
f(x) = \frac{\beta^\alpha}{(\alpha-1)!}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x\beta}\quad x>0.
$$

In this case the parameter $\beta$ could be any positive real number, but $\alpha$ can only take positive integer values. Show that a gamma prior for $\beta$ is conjugate. That is, show that if $\beta$ has a gamma prior, then the posterior for $\beta$ is also a gamma distribution. I looked at the solution and I do not understand how the did the very first line. The first line of the solution simply says

$$
f(\beta|x)\propto f(x|\beta,\alpha)\pi(\beta).\tag{1}
$$

I have tried to see why ($1$) is true and I get nowhere. My first attempt was to do
$$
\begin{align*}
f(\beta|x)&=\int f(\alpha,\beta|x) d\alpha\\
&= \int \frac{f(x|\alpha,\beta)f(\alpha,\beta)}{f(x)} d\alpha\\
&\propto\int f(x|\alpha,\beta)f(\alpha,\beta) d\alpha\\
&=\int f(x|\alpha,\beta)f(\alpha)f(\beta) d\alpha\\
&=f(\beta)\int f(x|\alpha,\beta)f(\alpha) d\alpha.
\end{align*}
$$
This doesn't seem to help at all, so I am stuck on how we can get to $(1)$. Any help would be much appreciated; I am very much struggling with this topic!

Comment: The first line is just a statement of Bayes theorem, when $\alpha$ is considered a constant (since the question is only about $\beta$)

Comment: So am I right in saying $f(\beta|x)\propto f(x|\beta)f(\beta)$ (application of Bayes), and then ($1$) follows because we can use the constancy of $\alpha$ to say $f(x|\beta)=f(x|\alpha,\beta)$?

Comment: I just don't think I really understand how we can treat $\alpha$ as a constant. Surely we are just trying to work out $f(\beta|x)$, and this is a quantity which depends on $\alpha$ which is a random variable? How does $\alpha$ become constant? I'm not getting the intuition. :( @J.Delaney

Comment: Assume that you know the value of $\alpha$, and $\beta$ is the only unknown parameter in the model. (you are right that the question is not super clear about it, but it is implied when asking only about $\beta$)